# What happens if I integrate my work Google account with my personal Google account?

Tags: google-account, google-workspace-for-business

I have two Google accounts, one for personal with a @gmail.com address, and one for work with a @mycompany.com address. I created the @mycompany.com account to use a separate Google calendar for work. Google has asked me a few times to "add an Gmail address" to this @mycompany.com. What exactly will happen if I add my @gmail.com email to my @mycompany.com account?

Comment: Can you provide the exact message? I expect that you're being prompted to add a recovery address. This would be helpful to recover your account if it gets hacked, but in no way otherwise changes the account and certainly doesn't merge anything.